# Proper way to get Oath2 access token and call another service in Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I want to get the oath2 access token and using this I want to call an another service.
Below code does the same it gets the access token and call an another API using that. Using the below code I am able to do what ever I want with the below code.
But I am new to Spring Security I just want to know if there is a better way to do this. Like rather than making a separate call to get the token and then call the service can i do it in a single call? Or Using any other class provided by Spring can I write this in a better way ?

```
public class TestAPIToken{
    
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/showEmployees", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView showEmployees(@RequestParam("code") String code) throws JsonProcessingException, IOException {
        String accessToken = getAccessToken();
                
        System.out.println("API Token ---------" + accessToken);

        HttpEntity<String> response = getResponseByCallingWithToken(accessToken);
        

        System.out.println("API Response ---------" + response.getBody());

        return null;
    }


    private HttpEntity<String> getResponseByCallingWithToken(String accessToken) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        headers.add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
        UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url)
                .queryParam("msisdn", msisdn)
                .queryParam("email", email);

        HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

        HttpEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
                builder.toUriString(), 
                HttpMethod.GET, 
                entity, 
                String.class);
        
        reponse.getBody();
        return response;
    }


    private String getAccessToken() {
        ResponseEntity<String> response = null;
        System.out.println("Authorization Code------" + code);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        // According OAuth documentation we need to send the client id and secret key in the header for authentication
        String encodedCredentials = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(credentials.getBytes()));

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedCredentials);
        
        MultiValueMap<String, String> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        
        body.add("scope","scope,value");
        body.add("grant_type","scope,value");

        HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(body, headers);

        String access_token_url = "http://localhost:8080/oauth2/token";
        

        ResponseEntity<TokenModel> response = restTemplate.exchange(access_token_url, HttpMethod.POST, request, TokenModel.class);
        String accessToken = response.getBody().access_token;
        return accessToken;
    }
}


class TokenModel{
    
    String access_token;
    String scope;
    String token_type;
    String expires_in;
    
}
```

I am new to Spring security. Please help even if this seems simple to you
NB: This question does  not have an exact duplicate

Comment: You can use `OAuth2RestTemplate`, and this will handle all the token exchange for you. It is also worth looking into `WebClient` as `OAuth2RestTemplate` will be deprecated in a future version.

Comment: @MarcosBarbero Can you please give me a sample code

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't have an example. However, with the information above you can easily find it on Google.